# Define new parameter in R conditional on multiple columns starting with the same name (combine mutate, ifelse and starts_with)

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

In my dataset, I have columns that indicate the presence of a disease; each column starts with the same letters:

```
"meta_var1"         "meta_var2"         "meta_var3"         "meta_var4"         "meta_var5"
```

I want to define a new parameter based on if any of these meta_var_parameters contains a certain value (in words: if any of the parameters meta_var1:meta_var10 contains x, then new_var == 1, else new_var == 0)

The following code works for one column at a time:

```
data <- mutate(data, liver_met = ifelse(str_detect(meta_var1, "C220"), 1, 0))
```

Output:

```
  table(data$liver_met)

0     1 
10330  1199
```

What I am looking for is a code that searches all columns at once; I tried this for example:

```
data <- mutate(data, liver_met = ifelse(str_detect(data[,31:40], "C220"), 1, 0))
```

This produces the following error

```
argument is not an atomic vector; coercingError in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `liver_met = ifelse(str_detect(data[, 31:40], "C220"), 1, 0)`.
x `liver_met` must be size 11529 or 1, not 10.
```

I understand this error code, but can't figure out a solution where it checks each column value after each other (and not the column name itself).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If we want to run this on multiple columns, use `if_any` to loop over the columns of interest (`31:40`), check for the substring "C220" in each of those columns and it returns `TRUE` if any of the column for a particular row is TRUE, coerce the logical to binary with `+`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
    mutate(liver_met = +(if_any(31:40, ~ str_detect(.x, "C220"))))
```